# Sync & Async Python FastAPI scripts on Google App Engine

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, asynchronous, fastapi

I've tried running the following py file `script.py` locally:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import asyncio
import time

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/async/')
async def func(text: str):
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    return {'text': text}


@app.get('/sync/')
async def func(text: str):
    time.sleep(5)
    return {'text': text}
```

using `uvicorn script:app --reload`

When making 10 concurrent requests to sync endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sync/?text=test`, each call takes 5 seconds and blocks the next, total time is 50 seconds

And when making 10 concurrent requests to async endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:8000/async/?text=test`, each call takes 5 seconds, total time is also 5 seconds as it's non-blocking.

---

I've tried deploying the script to Google App Engine using `entrypoint: gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker script:app` and did the same tests instead of locally, and got the following results:

When making 10 concurrent requests to sync endpoint, the total time is 12 seconds, all of the 10 requests executed on the same 1 instance. ( 1000 concurrent requests took 60 seconds on 20+ instances )

And when making 10 concurrent requests to async endpoint, the total time is 5 seconds, all of the 10 requests executed on the same 1 instance. ( 1000 concurrent requests took 30 seconds on 20+ instances )

---

Why on GAE the sync code took 12 seconds for the 10 concurrent requests instead of 50 seconds?

And how can I run all 10 requests simultaneously on GAE for the sync endpoint, to get them all in 5 seconds?

Comment: How you are making these requests ?

Comment: using k6 stress test ( 10 Virtual users with 10 Iterations )

Answer (score 3):

In your gunicorn command, you specified the option `-w 4`, which means 4 workers processes are spawned (https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-processes).

It's a common way to enable concurrency even on blocking synchronous code. Your 10 requests are split across the workers (10 requests * 5 seconds / 4 workers = 12.5 seconds).

If you run it like this:

`gunicorn -w 1 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker script:app`

You'll do experience 50 seconds of waiting.

But it's still strongly recommended to spawn several workers.

---

Now for the sync part, here is an interesting technical detail about FastAPI. If you define your route or dependency as `async`, it'll run in the main process, regardless of whether you are running blocking code or not inside.

This is why your `/sync` endpoint blocks.

However, if you define it as a standard non-async function, FastAPI will run it in a threadpool to avoid blocking the main process.

Doc: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/?h=technical#path-operation-functions

If you write your `/sync` endpoint like this:

```py
@app.get('/sync/')
def func(text: str):  # Just removed the async keyword
    time.sleep(5)
    return {'text': text}
```

You'll notice the endpoint is not blocking the main process anymore.

Comment: @mezo Was it helpful for you? :)

Comment: I have a clarifying question: are you saying that *by default* FastAPI uses the `threading` library when I don't specify anything?  And if I use `async` I am explicitly saying I will use `asyncio` (or hopefully soon `trio`), but I am also **implicitly saying "no" to `threading`**?  I did not know that, and it hugely helps me understand when it is best to make the extra effort to go to the `async`/`await` paradigm.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson We could say that, yes. Internally, non-async functions are handled by Starlette which relies on `run_in_executor` method of asyncio module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools
FastAPI however strongly encourages to use `async` functions by default. Unless you have heavy blocking I/O operations, it's better to run them as `async` to avoid the little overhead of running in a thread.